# How to properly squash commits using SourceTree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

We're using Git as our source control system, and I like to commit my code on a regular basis. This does mean that when I'm ready to push to the shared repo I've created quite a few nonsense commits that I'd like to squash away before pushing.

Using SourceTree that should be a simple thing, but I keep running into issues where not all selected commits are being squashed together. Let me show some images of what I do using a sample repo with some checkins:

[image: Initial situation]

I click the first checking and choose to 'rebase children interactively'

[image: Context menu]

A pop will appear with all the checkins:

[image: Popup]

On this popup I click the 'fifth' checkin and hit the squash with previous 3 times until the screen looks like this:

[image: Squashed in popup]

All's fine you'd think, but then when hitting the 'ok' button, this is what I end up with:

[image: End result]

Why oh why does it not include the 'Second' commit in the end result? Judging by the looks of the popup you'd think this is included as well. I can do the same thing again to get the second in there, but I just can't fathom why it works this way or how to squash them all in one go.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Odd. This sure looks like yet another argument to shun the fancy GUIs (which is my method: stick with CLI whenever possible for things I work with every day).

Comment: this is not how you do it. you drag the one's you want to squash into the "squasher" commit

Comment: I have this problem as well. I believe it is a bug. SourceTree will not squash the last item in the list. It is a bloody nightmare!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a bug in SourceTree, see [this bug report](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-13594). According to the bug history, it was closed as fixed in May 2021.

Comment: Thanks, I have since switched to using GitKraken which I find to work better for me.

Comment: @Robba Nevertheless, your question has been answered, so you should accept the answer and thus close out the question.

Comment: You're right :)